# run javascript at serverside

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, google-app-engine, strophe

Is there any way to run one same instance of JavaCcript(jQuery) on the server side and call it from a Java method?  :)

I am interested to know whether it is possible to run it on the server side (not clientside), like Google app engine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/). Apparently it supports a few javascript libraries, including jquery. http://ejohn.org/blog/bringing-the-browser-to-the-server/

Answer (score 3):

Jaxer by Aptana is the first Ajax server.  It has a javascript capability for the server-side.  Whether it does what you need is for you to decide.

http://jaxer.org/